# Limit of sum (ratio and root test)

Tags: calculus, limits

I have

$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} 3^{{(-1)}^{x}-x}$$

and to calculate this.

Using root test I get $3^{{(-1)}^{x}/x-1}$ so I conclude that it diverges because of $3^{{(-1)}^{x}/x}$,

but if I use Ratio test I get that it is equal to 1 -> no statement.

Why I have two different conclusions? Where am I making mistake?

Comment: I have not checked your calculations, but your results do not contradict each other.  You found that one test gave you a result while the other was inconclusive.

Comment: Hint: write down the first ~10 terms as powers of 3. What do you notice?

Answer (score 1):

The series converges. Your mistake is that $\lim_{n\to \infty} 3^{(-1)^n/n-1}=\frac13<1$ so convergence by the root test.

Actually, by observing that $3^{(-1)^n-n}\leq 3^{1-n}=3\cdot3^{-n},$ the series also can be seen to converge by comparison to
$$
3\sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^{-n}
$$

Comment: How to do with root and ratio test?

Answer (score 1):

Let's write down the first few terms of the series. Let $a_n = 3^{(-1)^n - n}$:
$$a_0 = 3, a_1 = 3^{-2}, a_2 = 3^{-1}, a_3 = 3^{-4}, a_4 = 3^{-3}, a_5 = 3^{-6}, a_6 = 3^{-5}, a_7 = 3^{-8}, a_8 = 3^{-7}, ...$$
Starting from $a_1$, we get a permutation of the terms of the geometric series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-n} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = 3^{(-1)^n - n} = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-n} = \frac{7}{2}.$$

Comment: But how to do with root and ratio test?